# Is this sentence natural semantically?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I resist to use *I turn the lights on brightly, redly, etc* instead of *I make it shine brightly, redly, etc.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use "I turn the lights on brightly"  This means that the act of turning on is bright.

You need to use an adjective to describe the light.

Instead you should say

> I turn the bright lights on.

or

> I turn the red lights on.